# Why is this sed command not producing unique domains?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed

I have tried to extract unique domains from a list of emails stored in a folder. I tried the following `sed` command:
The input given was readable to me as emails in the file.

```
sed 's/^.*@//g' "180 Millions Emails Data 1"/* | sort -u > OutPutUniqueDomain2.txt
```

The output is something like this:

```
®_18casper???!!!!!!!®@yahoo.com
®_18casper®@yahoo.com
§Ú°Û±o€£°÷°Ê€H§A§OœK¬Ü@home.com
³·³·---ŠÜ€ÖÁÙŠ³§A@hotmail.com
§AŠn¶Ü@hotmail.com
³aªoºÐ@hotmail.com
aol.com
Aol.com
Aol.Com
AOl.com
AOL.com
```

Expected Output is:

```
yahoo.com
home.com
hotmail.com
aol.com
```

I expect to have only unique domains in my output. I don't know even if the input file is properly fed still these type of unknown charcters are appearing in the file and even the domain is not extracted. They appear like an email. Also the domain is not unique. What wrong I have done with the command?

Comment: Add your input file to the question.

Comment: @heemayl I have already added the output what I am getting. Ok.. You want to see what  expected to me then I will add

Comment: I have edited the question hope this helps.

Comment: The most likely reason why the strings with the funny characters are not being edited by sed is that the files you are reading in are not in UTF-8 encoding. You will need to check with whoever provided you with those files what their encoding is, then convert them using `iconv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many thanks to @zwets for identifying the encoding issue and fix. The weird symbols should be destroyed by doing either

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-2 -t UTF-8 file | sed -r 's/\r//; s/.*@([^@]+)$/\L\1/' | sort -u > output
```

(Based on your comments in chat)

#### Explanation for `sed` command:

- `.*([^@]+)$` save the characters that are not `@` at the end of the line
- `\L` lowercase everything
- `\1` the saved part from earlier

Comment: Lets check .. Keeping fingers cross.. .:P

Comment: If you add `iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8` or `iconv -f windows-1252` (the obvious culprits) to the start of your pipeline, then I think the OP will also get rid of the l33t email addresses.

Comment: @zwets thanks! I'll have to let OP test your fix since I don't have their mysteriously evil file

Comment: @zwets May I know where you exactly wish to place your fix. I think that might be the problem.

Comment: @JafferWilson you would do `iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8 | sed -r 's/.*@([^@]+)$/\L\1/' | sort -u > output`

Comment: @Zanna What if I apply the fix to the output file. I think that will do the same magic. What I suppose....

Comment: no it won't work, you need to process the properly encoded text. See my edit @JafferWilson

Comment: ok I am checking this @Zanna

Comment: See this is the output: `yahoo.comYAHOO.COMYAHOO.comYahoo.comyahoo.com泊ahoo.com@yahoo.com籃色的蘋沼otmail.com屌worldnet.att.netWORLDNET.ATT.NETworldnet.att.netWingedWarrior我已覺很疲軌ahoo.comWhoa` still the character and the duplicate

Comment: @Zanna the solution didn't worked for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52795/discussion-between-zanna-and-jaffer-wilson).